# Data rows are being added with no data in my table, need a if statement to stop this?

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement

I am currently doing some work on a contact formular, I can make the text from my textboxes go into my coloumns, but if I dont type anything I dont want it to make a new row in the tabel with no data, which it is doing right now.

So I am guessing I need a if statement, but I dont know the syntax to make it.

This is my code:

```
    string Navn = TextBoxNavn.Text;
    string Emne = TextBoxEmne.Text;
    string Email = TextBoxEmne.Text;
    string Besked = TextBoxBesked.Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection

    (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Kontakt (Navn, Emne, Email, Besked) VALUES (@Navn, @Emne, @Email, @Besked)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", Navn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emne", Emne);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Besked", Besked);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: How about checking for string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxNavn.Text) ? If true for at least one text box, then skip the code for adding data to the database

Comment: hmm good idea, will try thanks :)

Comment: you can write it as a one long if statement with ||

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxNavn.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxEmne.Text) .... ) { return; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Navn) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Emne) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Besked))
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Kontakt (Navn, Emne, Email, Besked) VALUES (@Navn, @Emne, @Email, @Besked)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", Navn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emne", Emne);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Besked", Besked);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this.

1.Make your columns in your database table mandatory(By setting "Not Null" property).

2.Add a validation in your code itself where your text boxes are mandatory.(Required field validator).

3.Here simply add this "if"  condition

```
if(Navn !=null && Emne !=null && Email!=null && Besked !=null )
{
  //your code of insertion goes here.
}
```